# Create string variable to hold the first word of each array element

Tags: php

Essentially I have an array:

```
$names = array("firstName1 lastName1", "firstName2 lastName2", "firstName3 lastName3");
```

I want to create a string variable to hold firstName1, firstName2 and firstName3. Ideally the string should look like:

```
$firstNames = "firstName1, firstName2 & firstName3";
```

So I can create a script that looks like:

```
echo 'Thank you for your booking for'.$firstNames.' Your booking is now complete.'
```

I've tried looking at string concatenation via imploding with a 'for' loop, but didn't manage it. The array is not a fixed length, so I need the last element to be added with a " &".

Thanks for any help.

EDIT:

Using version 5.5.12, I have input:

```
$names = array("firstName1 lastName1", "firstName2 lastName2", "firstName3 lastName3");
$firstNames = '';
$finalFirstName = array_pop($names);
foreach ($names as $name)
{
  $firstNames = $firstNames . ' ' . reset(explode(' ', $name));
}
$firstNames = ' & ' . explode(' ', $finalFirstName)[0];
echo $firstNames;
```

And my output is:

```
Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference on line 8.
```

But I am seeing text of:

```
& firstName3
```

Comment: `$firstNames = implode(', ', array_column(array_map(function ($value) { return explode(' ', $value); }, $names), 0));` is probably a good start

Comment: You should eliminate the first `reset` as well

Comment: So that it reads: `$firstNames = $firstNames . ' ' . explode(' ', $name);`? That shows a `Notice: Array to string conversion on line 8` error

Comment: See if `preg_split` gives you better luck.

Comment: Won't that return array?

Answer (score 1):

I would use foreach instead of for loops for arrays with unknown length.

```
$firstNames = '';
foreach ($names as $name)
{
  $firstNames = $firstNames . ' ' . reset(explode(' ', $name));
}
```

To put `&` before the last name, I would pop off the last name and appending it in the way you need it to be, turning the code into.

```
$firstNames = '';
$finalFirstName = array_pop($names);
foreach ($names as $name)
{
  $firstNames = $firstNames . ' ' . reset(explode(' ', $name));
}
$firstNames = ' & ' . reset(explode(' ', $finalFirstName));
```

Comment: `explode(...)` returns an array. Change it to `reset(explode(...))` and it should work.

Comment: Well, I gave you a +1, Not sure if the downvoter noticed the same as I.

Comment: Thanks for your joint efforts. When I input the code though, I get an 'Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference' error though?

Comment: Which PHP version are you running?

Comment: If PHP >= 5.4, change `reset(explode(' ', $finalFirstName))` to `explode(' ', $finalFirstName)[0]`

Comment: You might have strict mode on. Is this within a framework of some sort? Did Henrique's alteration work for you?

Comment: I have updated the post to include yours and @HenriqueBarcelos solution. This is currently on local host: wamp. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
$tmp = array_map(
         function ($value) { return explode(' ', $value)[0]; },
         $names);
$firstNames = implode(', ', array_slice($tmp,0,count($tmp)-1)) . 
              " & " . end($tmp);

// firstName1, firstName2 & firstName3
```

Comment: This should not be relevant in 2015, but It's imporant to know that this code is for PHP 5.4+

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos  to use in 2014 or ealier, only one place should be changeв :)

Comment: PHP <= 5.3 don't support `explode(' ', $value)[0]`. PHP <= 5.2 don't support closures.

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos I don't use 5.2. Didnt think